# Criando id´s dinâmicos para minhas div´s no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Criei uma função que quando eu clico em uma `<div>`, ela cria uma outra `<div>` com os atributos de `class` e `id`. Nessa mesma função eu criei um laço `for` para poder adicionar atributos de `id` dinamicamente.

Eu quero que a cada `<div>` criada, o número no final do `id` seja incrementado, por exemplo:

```
#div-1, #div-2, #div-3...
```

Só que isso não está acontecendo pois ele simplesmente repete o mesmo `id`. Alguém pode me ajudar a ajustar minha função de uma maneira correta?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>tetes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="geral mt-4 ml-4" onclick="dispararLoop()">Clica aqui</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
function dispararLoop(){
for(i = 1; i < 2; i++){

    let criarDiv = document.createElement('div')

    let pegarCol = document.querySelector('.col')

    let id = document.createAttribute('id')

    id.value = 'div-' + (i * 5)

    criarDiv.setAttributeNode(id)

    pegarCol.appendChild(criarDiv)

    criarDiv.className = "d1"

    let criarParagrafo = document.createElement('p')

    criarDiv.appendChild(criarParagrafo)

    function Pessoa(nome, idade, sexo, profissao){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    let fernando = new Pessoa("Fernando", "28", "Masculino", "Dev")

    criarParagrafo.innerHTML = fernando.nome + " " + fernando.idade + " " + fernando.sexo + " " + fernando.profissao
}   
}
```

Comment: Porque precisas de IDs?

Comment: É mais pra caso de estudos mesmo, caso precise elaborar algo do tipo futuramente.

Answer (score 0):

Ele sempre cria o mesmo id, pois o valor de i é sempre 1, cada vez que vc clica no botão ele inicia o laço novamente do 1 e atribui o mesmo valor para a id.

Como a id é criada sempre que clica no botão pela ação do usuário não há a necessidade de realizar nenhum laço, porém é necessário que o valor gerado anteriormente continue armazenado para que possa incrementar e atribuir o novo id.

Por isso fiz a seguinte alteração no código javascript:

```
let cont = 0;

function dispararLoop(){
    let criarDiv = document.createElement('div')

    let pegarCol = document.querySelector('.col')

    let id = document.createAttribute('id')

    cont++;
    id.value = 'div-' + (cont)

    criarDiv.setAttributeNode(id)

    pegarCol.appendChild(criarDiv)

    criarDiv.className = "d1"

    let criarParagrafo = document.createElement('p')

    criarDiv.appendChild(criarParagrafo)

    function Pessoa(nome, idade, sexo, profissao){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    let fernando = new Pessoa("Fernando", "28", "Masculino", "Dev")

    criarParagrafo.innerHTML = fernando.nome + " " + fernando.idade + " " + fernando.sexo + " " + fernando.profissao   
}
```

Veja que foi criada uma variável global que vai manter a última numeração, ela inicializa em 0 e incrementa antes de atribuir a nova id.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou certinho, agora irei fazer dessa forma. Muito obrigado.